# SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane

Tags: c#, sql-server, view, entity-framework-4.1

I am working on entity Model. I updated the view to entity model, but this view not showing the correct data.

I searched on Google, and a few members suggested that add one more column to the view. So, I just added one column to the View:

`row_number() over (order by Employee.EmployeeID) as PK,`

In the Employee table the `EmployeeId` column is identity column.

I run the entity model. Now, the view is showing correct data. The problem is when I see the view design in SQL, it is not showing. When I remove the `row_number()` from the view, it is showing in the design of the view.

Comment: hi @kavitha, its almost 3 years difference between ur post & my comments, any way i am also facing the same prob, did you find any information related to the above issue ..

Answer (score 5):

Some queries are too complex to visualize for Management Studio. So even if your query is correct and display results, you will not see visual designer.